# Is it possible to modify swiper coverflow effect into card stack right view?

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I am using swiper.js https://swiperjs.com/ effect-coverflow

But what I want to achieve is this

[image]

Is there a way in Swiper to do this or any plugin?
I found a plugin vue-card-stack https://rodleviton.github.io/vue-card-stack/#basic but it's not working in vue 3 vite